# Separate values returned from AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My ajax functions returns two values, and when I call "data" they are displayed as one.

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'checkinfo.php',
    data: { address: "37.187.139.123", port: "26618" },
    dataType: 'html',
    async: true,
    success: function(data)
    {
    $("output").html(data);
    }
});
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
$SERVER_IP = $_REQUEST['address'];
$SERVER_PORT = $_REQUEST['port'];
$QUERY_PORT = $_REQUEST['port'];

$HEADS = "3D";
$show_max = "unlimited";
$SHOW_FAVICON = "on";

$TITLE = "My fancy Serverpage";
$TITLE_BLOCK_ONE = "General Information";
$TITLE_BLOCK_TWO = "Players";

$ping = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.minetools.eu/ping/' . $SERVER_IP . '/' . $SERVER_PORT . ''), true);
$query = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.minetools.eu/query/' . $SERVER_IP . '/' . $QUERY_PORT . ''), true);

if(empty($ping['error'])) { 
$version = $ping['version']['name'];
$online = $ping['players']['online'];
$max = $ping['players']['max'];
$motd = $ping['description'];
$favicon = $ping['favicon'];
}

if(empty($query['error'])) {
$playerlist = $query['Playerlist'];
}

echo $version;
echo $online;

?>
```

The output I get in the "output" element is" Version 1.80". Where as the $version variable is "Version 1.8" and the $online variable is "0". How do i separate these two values and assign them to two element different elements ex. output1 and output2.

Lastly, is there any better way to directly get the value from individual variables, rather than using  echo for them all and collecting them as one "data".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're dealing with a plain text/html response, which would need parsed. Also, the ajax function only returns one value. Anything echoed by the PHP script gets dumped into the ajax response.

You should change the `dataType` to `json`, and return the values as a json-encoded array:

```
die(json_encode(array(
    'version' => $version, 
    'online' => $online
)));
```

This can be accessed in javascript as:

```
data.version
data.online
```

ProTip: If you're not sure what's being returned, check the Network tab of Chrome's developer tools (or Firebug or whatever). Console.log() can be used to dump the var to the console for inspection, and doing the following will allow you to manipulate it directly in the console:

```
success: function(response) {
    console.log(resp=response); 
    /* open the console, and you can manipulate the var 'resp'  */
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! This solves all of my problems. Thanks for the clear instructions, Big props to you! Sorry if my description was unclear .